# Show that a continuous function from a closed set in a normal space to a cube can be extended to a continuous function to that space

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question in point set topology:

> Let $X$ be a normal space. Prove that any continuous function from a closed set in $X$ to a cube $I^n = \{(x_1,...x_n) \mid 0\leq x_i \leq 1 \space \forall i = 1,2,...,n \}$ can be extended to a continuous function $X \to I^n$

My original idea was to use the fact that if $f:K \to I^n$ is the given function, then $p \circ f : K\to I$ is continuous where $p: I^n \to I$ is the projection function, and maybe use Tietze's extension theorem on that composition, however, I don't really see how to progress from here. 
I also thought that maybe there is a use of some Urysohn function, but I think it's far-fetched. I would love for some hint for this because I think I'm missing something obvious. 
Thank's for the help!

Comment: In the end you take the diagonal product of the extensions of $p_1 \circ f, p_2 \circ f, p_3 \circ f$ to get the extension of $f$. It’s a standard categorical idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a function $f:K \to I^n$. Each component is of the form $f_i:X \to [0,1]$. By Tietze extension theorem, it can be extended to a continuous function $\tilde{f}_i:K \to [0,1]$. Therefore $\tilde{f} = (\tilde{f_1}, \dots, \tilde{f_n})$ is a continuous function of the form $\tilde{f}:K \to I^n$.

Comment: oh wow... I completely forgot about the components... thank you very much!

Comment: @LagrangeLover these components **are** the compositions with the projections you were talking about, so he just echoes your attempt.